# Прекачивание файла с одного места в другое средствами php

Tags: ftp, php

Нужно чтобы скачивался файл с удаленного хранилища и заливался на сервер в новую папку.

Answer (score 1):

[cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/curl.examples-basic.php) — ftp, http, авторизация, куки, редиректы.

Comment: спасибо, заработало